# PSQL import from CSV adding additional characters

Tags: postgresql, csv, psql

I have a CSV file where I'm importing a number of fields... One of the fields is a date type field with the format of '20120401'. In the CSV file, the length of this field for all rows is 8. I created a table in Postgres and specified the field to receive this data as a DATE type column. When I imported the CSV file, it threw an "invalid input error". To work-around this, I changed the table's type to VARCHAR thinking I could run an ALTER TABLE to change the data type afterwards. The import was successful, but the ALTER TABLE wasn't. I noticed that the first row's date has a length of 9 vs. the standard 8 for all the remaining rows. Somehow, in the import it gains another character which for the life of me, I can't identify where it comes from. I've done a bunch of TRIM operations (TRIM, BTRIM) but all still yield 9 characters. Any suggestions? If I remove this one row, the ALTER TABLE statement to change it to a DATE type works. So it's really only this row.

Sample below:

```
20150401    My  Gll ES  1A3AE039E352    GCE 0.2461158

20150401    My  Gll ES  1F63E45849F1    GCE 0.8670354
```

Comment: Can you include the first 2 or 3 lines from the CSV files directly in your question, formatted as code (with four spaces of indenting on each line)?  Maybe the source file has some special characters in it.

Comment: I actually tried re-saving the file in a CSV format and this seemed to work. The original file on the Mac was "CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited) (.csv)". I re-saved as "Comma Separated Values (.csv)" and this seemed to save a slightly reduced file and also removed the import issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Peering into my crystal ball, I see that it is a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (BOM) at the beginning of the file.

That would be UNICODE character U+FEFF, in UTF-8 it would be EF BB BF.

While byte order marks are useful in UTF16 encodings to determine the *endianness*, they are useless in UTF-8, but some operating systems use them as a marker that signifies “this file is UTF-8”.

You'll have to remove the character.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I see the <U+FEFF> when I query the first few lines once imported. This fails with a field of DATE type, but works for VARCHAR. I'm less clear on how exactly to remove it. Is this just an update with a TRIM function?

Comment: You can use `substr(charfield, 2)`. But I think you should clean the CSV file before importing.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks.